# Dynamic workflow with web page UI similar to jBPM

Tags: workflow, jbpm

My customer wants the ability to create dynamic workflows from a web page, using a jBPM-like user interface. Obviously jBPM is not meant to be used by a non-developer, and the jBPM UI is not meant to be run from a web client. Of course, this means we would have to re-create a subset of the jBPM user interface on a web page; and have server code that duplicates jBPM. At first glance, it appears implementing such a solution would be difficult and expensive (We do not have an unlimited budget). Has anyone else implemented a similar solution? or should we recommend that we not implement such a solution? Any recommendations or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am Intalio's chief architect. My company contributed the jBPM web editor called Wapama, renamed Process Designer by the jBPM team.

You can find this editor embedded in our product, Intalio|Create. Our product is completely web-based and packaged as a virtual machine. It features business process and integration capabilities, as well as a rapid application development platform to create modern business apps.

Answer (score 0):

While some jBPM UIs are targeted towards developers only (like for example the Eclipse plugins), others are web-based and targeted to business analysts and sometimes end users even.  Do you have a more detailed description of what capabilities you would like your non-developers to use?

For example, here's a screencast of some of the more business-user-focused tooling:
http://people.redhat.com/kverlaen/jbpm6-installer-console.swf

We have customers that have developed their own UI however, a recommended approach would be to reuse the existing REST service that exposes methods like getting tasks, starting processes, etc. and/or to embed the jBPM web Designer in your app.